# How to store the latest 100 items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular, how store the last 100 items to show. I implent it with array inserted by 'array.push'. if array is not working for this situation, how can I do.

code just as:

```js
        $interval(function()
        {
            $http.get("...")
              .success(function(){
                for(var index in response.logs)
                {
                   $scope.logs.push(response.logs[index]);
                } 
            
              })
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="log in logs">{{log.time}}:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{log.log}}</div>
```

Comment: reverse the array and select the first 100

Comment: I've add the brief code, thank you

Comment: array slice is a good option

Comment: array may be not the proper one,  the num of logs become goes larger and larger, but ouly the last 100 items used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var lastValues = a.slice(-3); // -100 in your situation

// lastValues = [3,4,5]
```

Comment: @SaE How is this relevant ?

Comment: But when the num of the logs grows, the array may not be the efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

I find the array is not the best practive here. As the logs increase with 1sec interval. When the array length becomes too long, the browser will become slow and then to freeze. 
So I choose a circular buffer [Cbuffer](https://github.com/trevnorris/cbuffer) to this situation.

```
var cbuffer = new CBuffer(100);      // empty buffer with size of 100
$interval(function()
{
    $http.get("...")
        .success(function(){
        for(var index in response.logs)
        {
            cbuffer.push(response.logs[index]);
            $scope.logs = cbuffer.toArray();
        } 
    })
}, 1000);
```